# Fail to produce valid PDF from pgfplots sample code

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart, dvipdfmx

I use the following the pgfplots sample code:

```
\documentclass[varwidth=true, border=2pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            symbolic x coords={a small bar, a medium bar, a large bar},
            xtick=data
          ]
            \addplot[ybar,fill=blue] coordinates {
                (a small bar,   42)
                (a medium bar,  50)
                (a large bar,   80)
            };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I successfully compile it to a .dvi file but when I create a PDF from the .dvi file (using `dvipdfm` or `dvipdfmx`) I get a blank page with some scattered tokens on it! no bar chart!

This reproduces on two machines - both windows and linux. I get a very similar behavior when using a sample code of the `bchart` package.

Comment: Why not creating a PDF from the code itself?

Comment: Thanks! using pdflatex fixed the problem. But why using latex + dvipdfm doesn't work?

Comment: I don't know, I never compiled such a format. But I saw no reason to do it in this instance, since you could simply compile it from the code itself. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PGF needs to know how to generate the special graphics instructions in the output files, and these differ between `pdflatex` and `latex/dvipdfm`.

Thus, you can either use `pdflatex` (or `latex / dvips`) and configure nothing special, or you have to use a special entry in the `.tex` file in order to make PGF aware of the following dvi utilities (which are beyond PGF's knowledge).

The "special entry" is described in the following quote of the `pgfplots` manual:

> Furthermore, pgf needs to know a driver so that the DVI file can be 
>   converted to the desired output. Depending on your system, you need
>   the following options:
>
> ```
> - latex/dvips does not need anything special because dvips is the default driver if you invoke latex.
> - pdflatex will also work directly because pdflatex will be detected automatically.
> - latex/dvipdfm requires to use
> ```

```
   \def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvipdfm.def}
   %\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-pdftex.def}
   %\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvips.def}
   %\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvipdfmx.def}
   %\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-xetex.def}
   \usepackage{pgfplots}.
```

> The uncommented commands could be used to set other drivers explicitly. Please read the corresponding sections in [pgfmanual.pdf, Section
>   7.2.1 and 7.2.2] if you have further questions. These sections also contain limitations of particular drivers.
>
> The choice which won't produce any problems at all is pdflatex.